# SSRS reports Data Source

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got a few SSRS reports that have been created for me.

I want to know if I could view the data source/ connection string to those reports...
for example information like which databases and tables these reports are generated from... or the connection string

I can go to Reports Manager and navigate to the report I want and go to Manage section. but all I see is this,

[image]

Is there another place I can see amend this data source/ connection string

Could someone advice me on this please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to open the .rdl file(s) in Visual Studio? If you can, do so, and check the solution explorer window. There should be a folder called "Shared Data Sources." Double click the .rds within that, and you can edit the connection string. It's a little more complex than this makes it sound, but in 90% of cases, this should be all you need to know. If this doesn't work for you, let me know, and we can get more specific form there.

Comment: Hi
I can Open up the .RDL file in Visual Studio. but there is nothing under "Shared Data Sources" folder. 
However under Report Data Window there's a "Data Sources" folder under which there's a DataSource1 File. I can Double click on this and open it.
This opens a "Data Source Properties" window, on this there is a Connection String....

Comment: That should work, too. All of our reports have that data source linked to a shared data source that contains the actual info. If you can see the connection string there, though, you should be able to make whatever changes you need to make.